# Learning Phrasal verbs and idioms

Tags: learning

I would like to learn about phrasal verbs and idioms in English.Which book(s) would you recommend for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this useful http://a4esl.org/q/h/idioms.html   It  contains a bunch of Self-Study Idiom Quizzes.